# How can I get the URI from the Cling Renderer?

Tags: upnp, cling

I've now made my cling renderer work after some efforts, that is, the media commanded by a remote control point, can be played/rendered by my renderer(run on Linux, using cling library).

The next I want to achieve is to do something interesting with the media, which requires knowing the URI of the playing media. Does Cling provide some API to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

See the Cling manual and the MediaRenderer spec:
http://4thline.org/projects/cling/support/manual/cling-support-manual.xhtml#javadoc.example.mediarenderer.AVTransportTest.testCustomPlayer..

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement an statemachine which extends AVTransportStateMachine, then implement different state. Cling will call the state's setTransportURI, so you can got the URI.